# How is this Alpha Blending equation to understand?

Tags: surface, alphablending, blending

So I was reading a Document about Displacement Mappings and Surface Blendings and came across this equation which is supposed to be a Alpha-Blending equation:

[image]

while v1,...,vn are supposed to be the value vector and w1,....,wn the weight vector (is how the document describes it).

To tell what my interpretation of this equation is, is that considering n being the number of surfaces we are trying to blend together the value vectors are supposed to represent as the name says the value (probably color related?) of each surface and the weight vector basically describing the value preference of each surface (so the higher the weight value the more we would see the color of that one surface after the blend). The multiplication and division part is something what i do not fully understand (just interpreting it as the 'it just works like that' part of the equation)

I couldn't find any similar equation anywhere so far so I figured out that either I didn't search deep enough or I am not understanding something that is supposed to be very obvious and I wanted to make sure that fully understand this equation for further read in the document which bases on this idea.

Comment: Where did you get the equation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey from a document called 'Quadtree Displacement Mapping with Height Blending'. This equation is simply the introduction in the surface blending part of this documentary so it doesn't tell me much except throwing this equation at me

Comment: If you're just interested in alpha blending, there are better ways to learn it than from an article where you don't understand the math.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would not say interested but I just have to prepare a presentation about this topic, which mostly focus on the mapping and blending techniques proposed in the document. And I just thought that it wouldn't hurt to know what some of the equations which just flies by does, in case someone asks me